# How to initialize N dimensional arrays in C without using loop

Tags: c, arrays, matrix, initialization

I want to initalize a 3 x 3 matrix with first two rows as 0's and last row as 1's. I have declared a 2D array `int matrix[3][3]`

I want to initialize it without using loops as shown below

> 0 0 0
>   0 0 0
>   1 1 1

I would also like a solution for N dimiensional array

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
int matrix[3][3] = {
    { 0, 0, 0 },
    { 0, 0, 0 },
    { 1, 1, 1 }
};
```

Or, the more compact:

```
int matrix[3][3] = {
    [2] = { 1, 1, 1 }
};
```

The solution generalizes for `N` so long as `N` is fixed. If `N` is large, you can use mouviciel's answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/201101/how-to-initialize-an-array-in-c).

Comment: Thanks again, also looking for an N dimensional solution

Comment: @AndyStowAway This solution works for N-dimensional array as long as N is a fixed number known at compile time.

Answer (score 0):

```
matrix[0][2] = matrix[0][1] = matrix[0][0] =
matrix[1][2] = matrix[1][1] = matrix[1][0] = 0;
matrix[2][2] = matrix[2][1] = matrix[2][0] = 1;
```

or

```
#include <string.h>
...
memset(matrix, 0, sizeof(matrix));
matrix[2][2] = matrix[2][1] = matrix[2][0] = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

In your case, you could do with

```
int a[3][3] = {{}, {}, {1,1,1}};
```

Notice that the empty curly braces will be automatically filled with 0.

Now, if you want

```
0 0 0
0 0 0
1 0 0
```

you could do it with:

```
int a[3][3] = {{}, {}, {1,}};
```

For details, please look at [How to initialize all members of an array to the same value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/201101/how-to-initialize-an-array-in-c) (this is for unidimensional array, but it will help you understand what is written above.)

Also, http://c-faq.com/~scs/cclass/notes/sx4aa.html is a good resource for array initialization.

Answer (score 0):

For an constant integer expression `N` (say a macro or an `enum` constant) you'd have to "unroll" the initializer. There are macro tricks to do this when `N` expands to a decimal constant, but they are a bit involved. [P99](http://p99.gforge.inria.fr/p99-html/group__basic__list__operations.html) provides such macros, with that you could write

```
#define N 23

int matrix[N][N] = {
    [N-1] = P99_DUPL(N, 1),
};
```

This lets you easily change `N` if you need it without having to touch anything else in your code for the update.